# To create new word document after replacing placeholder and maintain format as of old word document

Tags: openxml, c#-2.0, streamreader, file-handling

I'm having following code,in this code i am reading the content of file as a stream,
after reading it as stream I need to crate new document which will maintain the format after replacement of placeholder,if I m reading file from path it is replacing placeholder write in new file and show it properly with format ,but if im reading the same content using stream it doesnot throw any error,it creates the file ,but while opening it shows file corrupted

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System;

using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class newprogramme
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
       {
            #region Document Body


        Stream fileStram = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(documentBody));
        WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileStram, true);
        //WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\Users\gaurav12799\Desktop\TestDoc.docx", true);
        Body body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

        var paras = body.Elements<Paragraph>();

        foreach (var para in paras)
        {
            foreach (var run in para.Elements<Run>())
            {
                foreach (var text in run.Elements<Text>())
                {
                    if (text.Text.Contains("name"))
                    {
                        text.Text = text.Text.Replace("name", "gaurav");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();

        //WordprocessingDocument newDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(doc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(),false);

        string fileName = "D:\\Test.doc";

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            Stream stream = doc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream();
            byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            fileStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            fileStream.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

}

This is my stream format data

```
            string documentBody =  @"UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQAJJIeCgQEAAI4FAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA    AAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA    AAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0lE1Pg0AQhu8m/geyVwPbejDGlPag9ah    NrPG8LkPZyH5kZ

     /v17x1KS6qhpVq9kMAy7/vMCzOD0UqX0QI8KmtS1k96LAIjbabMLGWv08f4lkUYhMlEaQ2kbA3IRsPLi8F07QAjqjaYs     iIEd8c5ygK0wMQ6MHSSW69F

oFs/407IDzEDft3r3XBpTQAT4lBpsOHgAXIxL0M0XtHjmsRDiSy6r1+svFImnCuVFIFI+cJk31zirUNClZt3sFAOrwiD8VaH6uSww    bbu
maLxKoNoInx4Epow+NL6jGdWzjX1kByXaeG0ea4kNPWVmvNWAiJlrsukOdFCmR3/QQ4M6xLw7ylq3RPt31QoxnkOkj52dx4a46rpp    LbYq
```

+12gxAopFNMvv6CcVfouFXuRFjC+8u/UeyJd4LkNBpT8V7CCYn/MIxGuhMi0LwD31z7Z3NsZI5Z0mRMvHVI

+8P/ou3dgqiqYxo5Bz4oaFZE24g1jrR7zu4Pqu2WQdbizTfbdPgJAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQAekRq38wAAAE4CAAALAAgCX3JlbHMvLnJlbHM

gogQCKKAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAjJLbSgNBDIbvBd9hyH032woi0tneS
KF3IusDhJnsAXcOzKTavr2jILpQ217m9OfLT9abg5vUO6c8Bq9hWdWg2JtgR99reG23iwdQWchbmoJnDUfOsGlub9YvPJGUoTyMMaui4rOGQSQ

+ImYzsKNchci+VLqQHEkJU4+RzBv1jKu6vsf0VwOamabaWQ1pZ

+9AtcdYNl/WDl03Gn4KZu/Yy4kVyAdhb9kuYipsScZyjWop9SwabDDPJZ2RYqwKNuBpotX1RP9fi46FLAmhCYnP83x1nANaXg902aJ5x687HyFZLBZ9

e/tDg7MvaD4BAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQB8O5c5IgEAALkDAAAcAAgBd29yZC9fcmVscy9kb2N1bWVudC54bWwucmVscyCiBAEooAABAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKyTTU

+EMBCG7yb

+B9K7FFZdjdmyFzXZq67x3C1TaISWdMYP/r0VswrKogcuTWaavs/TSbtav9VV9AIejbOCpXHCIrDK5cYWgj1sb08uWYQkbS4rZ0GwFpCts

+Oj1R1UksIhLE2DUUixKFhJ1FxxjqqEWmLsGrBhRztfSwqlL3gj1ZMsgC

+SZMl9P4Nlg8xokwvmN/kpi7ZtE8h/ZzutjYJrp55rsDSC4AhE4WYYMqUvgATbd+Lgyfi4wuKAQm2Ud+g0xcrV/JP

+Qb0YXowjtRXgo6HyRmtQ1Mf/3JrySA94jI
z5H6PoyL1BdPUUfjknnsILgW96V/JuTacczud00M7SVu6qnsdXa0ribE6JV9jd/3qVveZehA8+XPYOAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQBRbm8SgQIAA

EwHAAARAAAAd29yZC9kb2N1bWVudC54bWysVclu2zAQvRfoPwg85NRYsuK4gRrZQJqlORQwmvZc0BQlsZY4AklZdb+

+Q2qxEwVplh4EcZl5897MkDxf/i4Lb8uVFiBjMp0ExOOSQSJkFpMf36+Pz4inDZUJLUDymOy4JsvF

+3fnTZQAq0sujYcQUkdNxWKSG1NFvq9ZzkuqJ6VgCjSkZsKg9CFNBeN

+Ayrxw2AauFGlgHGtMd5nKrdUkw6uHKNBxSXGSkGV1OgJqMwvqdrU1TGiV9SItSiE2SF2MO9hICa1klFH6HggZF2illD36z3USMUjcVvPyy4DLqKveI

EcQOpcVHsZr0VDiXlPafuUiG1Z9HZNNZ2N4g2Sn1ODS0UbLMUecAT3SDKS1qks2jzY+u6r+hBxGjwlpquIhRg4PIfC/Zg9k5IKOcC8LjWHycUT8Zb

+vlFQVwOdSrwN7VZuBix7MF/ALJi7k3coTb8IYHR073JaceKVLLrNJCi6LpBRM515tiPJAi

+LNSQ7+6+8JsLLJvkWkyAIT6fhySnply55SuvCjHdWB0sOZKXs7xdDzy0tYqJElhviL859jNBurgE29na4M1QZtBMJgthQkpZI7ucNXFC2sT6WXGt7J

ZPBsgN7OWeHeE/m9cVJeIU3Uqd8LNMGcYrM4ovwjgrzyX6W6FGGY/w+WGXG6UNDq/J/EPtn/g+JQeNRxb0d1Mvlo2w0Z2alepUPS5bd/cGtBt

+YMJy5QuQ4Pj3DcZux7Cu1zgYqXJ+1Jq6u++kajIFyPy94it3SG+ecJhxv74+hg08BzME0q42bduEYFBqj6Yoy7Abr4ljgm3ajhO2CQki

+EoYhy5O528WstxJdAdqGxrX+GVz8BQAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEAMN1
DKagGAACkGwAAFQAAAHdvcmQvdGhlbWUvdGhlbWUxLnhtbOxZT2/bNhS/D9h3IHRvYyd2Ggd1itixmy1NG8Ruhx5piZbYUKJA0kl9G9rjgAHDumGHFd

hth2FbgRbYpfs02TpsHdCvsEdSksVYXpI22IqtPiQS

+eP7/x4fqavX7scMHRIhKU/aXv1yzUMk8XlAk7Dt3R72L615SCqcBJjxhLS9KZHetY3337uK11VEYoJgfSLXcduLlErXl5akD8NYXuYpSWBuzEWMFby

KcCkQ+AjoxmxpuVZbXYoxTTyU4BjI3hqPqU/QUJP0NnLiPQaviZJ6wGdioEkTZ4XBBgd1jZBT2WUCHWLW9oBPwI

+G5L7yEMNSwUTbq5mft7RxdQmvZ4uYWrC2tK5vftm6bEFwsGx4inBUMK33G60rWwV9A2BqHtfr9bq9ekHPALDvg6ZWljLNRn

+t3slplkD2cZ52t9asNVx8if7KnMytTqfTbGWyWKIGZB8bc/i12mpjc9nBG5DFN

+fwjc5mt7vq4A3I4lfn8P0rrdWGizegiNHkYA6tHdrvZ9QLyJiz7Ur4GsDXahl8hoJoKKJLsxjzRC2KtRjf46IPAA1kWNEEqWlKxtiHKO7ieCQo1gzw

OsGlGTvky7khzQtJX9BUtb0PUwwZMaP36vn3r54/RccPnh0/+On44cPjBz9aQs6qbZyE5VUvv/3sz8cfoz

+efvPy0RfVeFnG//rDJ7/8/Hk1ENJnJs6LL5/89uzJi68+/f27RxXwTYFHZfiQxkSim+QI7fMYFDNWcSUnI3G

+FcMI0/KKzSSUOMGaSwX9nooc9M0pZpl3HDk6xLXgHQHlowp4fXLPEXgQiYmiFZx3otgB7nLOOlxUWmFH8yqZeThJwmrmYlLG7WN8WMW7ixPHv71JCn

UzD0tH8W5EHDH3GE4UDklCFNJz/ICQCu3uUurYdZf6gks+VuguRR1MK00ypCMnmmaLtmkMfplW6Qz+dmyzewd1OKvSeoscukjICswqhB8S5pjx
Op4oHFeRHOKYlQ1+A6uoSsjBVPhlXE8q8HRIGEe9gEhZteaWAH1LTt/BULEq3b7LprGLFIoeVNG8gTkvI7f4QTfCcVqFHdAkKmM/kAcQohjtcVUF3+V

uhuh38ANOFrr7DiWOu0+vBrdp6Ig0CxA9MxEVvrxOuBO/gykbY2JKDRR1p1bHNPm7ws0oVG7L4eIKN5TKF18/rpD7bS3Zm7B7VeXM9olCvQh3sjx3uQ

jo21+dt/Ak2SOQEPNb1Lvi/K44e//54rwony++JM

+qMBRo3YvYRtu03fHCrntMGRuoKSM3pGm8Jew9QR8G9Tpz4iTFKSyN4FFnMjBwcKHAZg0SXH1EVTSIcApNe93TREKZkQ4lSrmEw6IZrqSt8dD4K3vUb

OpDiK0cEqtdHtjhFT2cnzUKMkaq0Bxoc0YrmsBZma1cyYiCbq/DrK6FOjO3uhHNFEWHW6GyNrE5lIPJC9VgsLAmNDUIWiGw8iqc+TVrOOxgRgJtd

+uj3C3GCxfpIhnhgGQ+0nrP

+6hunJTHypwiWg8bDPrgeIrVStxamuwbcDuLk8rsGgvY5d57Ey/lETzzElA7mY4sKScnS9BR22s1l5se8nHa9sZwTobHOAWvS91HYhbCZZOvhA37U5P

ZZPnMm61cMTcJ6nD1Ye0+p7BTB1Ih1RaWkQ0NM5WFAEs0Jyv/chPMelEKVFSjs0mxsgbB8K9JAXZ0XUvGY+KrsrNLI9p29jUrpXyiiBhEwREasYnYx

+B+HaqgT0AlXHeYiqBf4G5OW9tMucU5S7ryjZjB2XHM0ghn5VanaJ7JFm4KUiGDeSuJB7pVym6UO78qJuUvSJVyGP/PVNH7Cdw

+rATaAz5cDQuMdKa0PS5UxKEKpRH1+wIaB1M7IFrgfhemIajggtr8F

+RQ/7c5Z2mYtIZDpNqnIRIU9iMVCUL2oCyZ6DuFWD3buyxJlhEyEVUSV6ZW7BE5JGyoa

+Cq3ts9FEGom2qSlQGDOxl/7nuWQaNQNznlfHMqWbH32hz4pzsfm8ygl
FuHTUOT278QsWgPZruqXW+W53tvWRE9MWuzGnlWALPSVtDK0v41RTjnVmsr1pzGy81cOPDivMYwWDREKdwhIf0H9j8qfGa/dugNdcj3obYi

+HihiUHYQFRfso0H0gXSDo6gcbKDNpg0KWvarHXSVss36wvudAu

+J4ytJTuLv89p7KI5c9k5uXiRxs4s7Njaji00NXj2ZIrC0Dg/yBjHmM9k5S9ZfHQPHL0F3wwmTEkTTPCdSmDooQcmDyD5LUezdOMvAAAA//8DAFBLAw

QUAAYACAAAACEA0c5eAHwDAACwCAAAEQAAAHdvcmQvc2V0dGluZ3MueG1stFZbb9s2FH4f0P8g6HmOLnayTYhStGndtYjXYUp/ACUdy0R4A0lZcX/9D

kkxapA0KFbsydS5fOf28dCXr+85S46gDZWiTouzPE1AdLKnYqjTL7fb1e9pYiwRPWFSQJ2ewKSvr179cjlVBqxFM5MghDAV7+r0YK2qssx0B

+DEnEkFApV7qTmx

+KmHjBN9N6pVJ7kilraUUXvKyjy/SGcYWaejFtUMseK009LIvXUuldzvaQfzT/TQPxI3eL6T3chBWB8x08AwBynMgSoT0fh/RcMSDxHk

+FIRR86i3VTkL1nO5U5S9w8eP5Kec1BadmAMDoizUC4nVDzAFJsnQA+tPsNWZyF25qDQvcj9acncsCf

+z0w7TPGGtproMGYkgMuCd9XHQUhNWoakmopNeoWM

+iolT6ZKge5wSHX6R55mTo61yH1jiQXUGgWMeXp2DAhiTdWgCUdi1WmQeJ8e9mRk9pa0jZUKjY4EU/6tnCG7A9Gks6AbRTpEu5bCasmiXS//kvYaSaq

xhyGJQFmXTjg1gf7oIQjHIoJ0pvRO9uAyGzV90qfv9tk5+CyxHb6G5wNJvK6a9oClMWjsicEWk2/oV3gj+k

+jsRQviSf2T2TwUgIgXOTPeLlvTwq2QOyIbfqfgvlJbBlVO6q11B9Fj9T42WBZHKIbJ+6+3sTDP1LaOIY8L8+Lcn0eeu
HMFk2+Li+Ki+c03/fZvl2X770Pxp

+j8srtjb/11WU4uVEmPNDgmvBWU5Ls3GZBQvCq1XdvqYj6FnCzwreaZmyjcrUKCsMJY1vkelT4C8Crnhr1DvYelu2IHhbc2UI/K8V79ekBy11T0B

+0HFWINmmiwohiuGKzmfGosDeUR7kZ2yZ6CdwO36hG0X8+ageYLe2ZKouPiqf6DRFDnASI1ZfGmeJEmW7cwwM7ohReaTRph6JOGR0OtnD0tPjV4wPkP

9qhnHWl1+GX0/kP0rnK0Ho+OINwRKv5sMjWUbZeZLheg91mkZ1H2fkiu4gyfACn6oD3SeNyu8OlEY9OvpeMyQn6P6OwTp

+IQhPMgSjAubrdh6SWlRfMy9AkxwrucbFCTy2+64r2nNzjs5+XnpazNSMnOdpHtg7JGatH0qQnlqC7H9UjZxwdburHuUxVDx1FOjYn3i6r9iwkzqixD

SjcylZqLNkvwl898vJX4+pfAAAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEAF6AWTgIBAACsAQAAFAAAAHdvcmQvd2ViU2V0dGluZ3MueG1sjNDBSgMxEAbgu

+A7LLm32ZUisnS3IFLxIoL6AGl2dhvMZMJMaqxPb9qqIF56yySZj5l/ufpAX70Di6PQqWZeqwqCpcGFqVOvL

+vZjaokmTAYTwE6tQdRq/7yYpnbDJtnSKn8lKooQVq0ndqmFFutxW4BjcwpQiiPIzGaVEqeNBp

+28WZJYwmuY3zLu31VV1fq2+Gz1FoHJ2FO7I7hJCO/ZrBF5GCbF2UHy2fo2XiITJZECn7oD95aFz4ZZrFPwidZRIa07wso08T6QNV2pv6eEKvKrTtwx

SIzcaXBHOzUH2Jj2Jy6D5hTXzLlAVYH66N95SfHu9Lof9k3H8BAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQCG7lbeXwgAAHJAAAAaAAAAd29yZC9zdHlsZXNXa

XRoRWZmZWN0cy54bWzEW21zmzgQ/n4z9x8Yvqd+SZpcM3U7adJeM9OXtE7mPst
YjpkA4gDHSX/9rVYgYzCwG+jcJwch7bOr3X1WdrRv3z+FgfMok9RX0cydvBq7jow8tfSj+5l7d/vp6C/XSTMRLUWgIjlzn2Xqvn/35x9vt

+dp9hzI1AEBUXq+jb2Zu86y

+Hw0Sr21DEX6KvS9RKVqlb3yVDhSq5XvydFWJcvRdDwZ419xojyZpoB2KaJHkbq5uLAuTcUyAqyVSkKRpa9Ucj8KRfKwiY9Aeiwyf

+EHfvYMssenhRg1czdJdJ4rdGQV0kvOjUL5R7EiqVlxANesvFLeJpRRhoijRAagg4rStR/vzHipNDBxXaj02GbEYxgU87bx5KSGZ02m

+OAqEVtwxU5gTdyBzViaRWFg9kH7d+fVqsTJuM2Y3CNahNWBosI

+ZqFJKPzIinnZ1pQ3F/KhT3z/nahNbNWJ/X7SrqMHK0unJUOz8SlmXtm0lCWglrrztYil64Te

+fV9pBKxCECj7eTE0RHpvgOqWCrvSq7EJshS/ZjcJPlj/oQfn1SUpc72XKSe798ChYCU0AeBny

+i1HfhjRRpdpH64uDLtZ518I2XZiVpH/yl7440YvoLZD6KYOZOp8XIpdZgbywQ0X0xJqOju3lZk5lrhxYgd+aK5Gh

+oYWN0Mzis2RuvGc8PKEqsfAg8wBHrDIJJAQspnECX3t3egaMZh5+bvTmik2mchAUAGBlsfBY2XHgJmCquWFseCtXX5T3IJfzDF7MXMSCwbvrm8RXCd

DozH3zRmPC4FyG/md/uZS6QORjd9HaX8p/1jK6S

+VyN/7jE9JzLtFTmygD9U/PMAqCdPnxyZOxpkkQHQnt4W96AXAYuKOEgwpt/J02ZqCCioP/FpAT48ODKGspdElzUP9WILR60xtoqi0qG4ByWboe9xdx

0l/E6/4iMHj77cVZfy3gINPXIyY2SlFJd2qmPBN85X04ftMSsnpFLYo6V9SCpnNFLUY6V9RConNFLQI6V9Qc3rmi5t/OFTV3tq7wBBJXNYqOcTdIiX3

rZwHUyQ6mm/SkurzUODci
EfeJiNeOLqxVtdvIcr5ZZDRVkU5fTpbzLFH6uNmxI1Cddeq+mJM/hvFapD6cyruAem79rT76OH8nPhxfO6Bem+Cr2YQHk4Ml7CYQnlyrYCkT51Y

+GY8y1n9TztycMjqV6+nWL/79OnPgVKhLbifYacOmN++Ekf/FT3EPWqv5aYMpXcJJPjxtiMtm4V/l0t

+ExdYQTiOnhs8Zbq5AoIrtW3SiXVTPrk4rtAMoJphywTcB5RP0N8WFL1/7mKK/KUUvlE/Q3xSuF8rH

+Gj3L5tpruBnFYeUXmfs3L1UgUpWm6DIgU56OGNnsIWgmcBOYiufRBJn7Azeo0/nwvPgmxslTtm+2PEoA4XtDoOCyUa3he2UCu1NGBaxHVTBmjKw

+nEtA4hNuj/lo69/BOYWA2Rpe9bsTOfjhh2AEkQ6Q//YqKz7DD1t4DwqynUEP5ek0qGhHTdkHhUtjydT7xg

+7lf4GED9KiADqF8pZAA1xEfzmcfWRDpI/

+LIwGLTsq1iGHZkZj5jM7MF4pWAgeom4fzVkL3NsVCvmwQUtoPqdZOAwvZOpZbZuknAGqxuErAaqkazj8qcyjGKXTfLQPYkQLBoGPImAA1D3gSgYcib

ANSfvLtBhiNvAhabGyynlsmbAIRTOF/1LVCZvAlAbG4wbJf/ZlTUPZTS/uV2APImoLAdVCdvAgrbO03kTcDCKZxIqGBZqiNgDUPeBKBhyJsANAx5E4C

GIW8C0DDkTQDqT97dIMORNwGLzQ2WU8vkTQBi04MFKpM3AQincLjhIHlj1v928iagsB1UJ28CCts7FUK1h1QCFttBFSxL3gQsnMIJhhwLg5tj1DDkTb

BoGPImAA1D3gSgYcibANSfvLtBhiNvAhabGyynlsmbAMSmBwtUJm8CEJsbDpI3JuNvJ28CCttBdfImoLC9UyFUy3MELLaDKliWvAlYGC

+9yZsAhFNeCsSxaBjyJlg0DHkTgIYhbwJQf/LuBhmOvAlYbG6wnFombwIQmx4sUJm8CUBsbjhI3pgjv
528CShsB9XJm4DC9k6FUC15E7DYDqpgWaojYA1D3gQgDMze5E0AwikvAMIs4rhpGPImWDQMeROA+pN3N8hw5E3AYnOD5dQyeROA2PRggcrkTQBic4O

+Zwv3RcnXUycNQUC9Z1DcaiADThucRAXMDfwpVzKBrkLZfTukJ2BhIQOxITyoJn5Q6sGhXew+bggQMpS/CHyFV7qf8ZZOqRHh+Kylk

+D2+6Xz2TTA1NZhSO3fvIHuoXK7ELYn6cYh0DN7jqFlJy5ulmtp0CCk

+7ryFiDsCb2GhqC8rUcv1n0+MBGbqvJh/L9tjgp/AyIurEN5a8DyoCOqBSq/8G7vIOF19ypww614VGTXklGomd

+O352hzLy9O5qtemf6JniLznhTvHWPHJxivFpXEJqzUKUuDcFli8C0mMEf19ESLNzm3VnGmcsnYUTB

+0sZBF8FNqRlKm6eGshVZt5OxlgBK6IWKstU2Lw

+wQviqMkhARAOZWXMozaiOU6iTbiQSX7dvDEkdeXATrT9kDR3XRtCgbrTzbrtpYtNkA8iCJSK8CZ/NVjzd+aaP

+q1ENBm9113zdXSCFoEH4rxktBLyJz

+0QN94TpkEHQ8nr6eTKHfBTVqalzEf8jmbYsn9uFw22LeIgkfe72fM/dWrFUodP5gV2d5wINm1fy1yQDbxDk5zXPi166J04yBb6DltC1+9njG26QQvt

gsWaW16ga3ec7ZuaDivoOMhdY0OJPpyGav4Tb8D/tdZEf67j8AAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQAarjuLTAEAAIcCAAARAAgBZG9jUHJvcHMvY29yZ

S54bWwgogQBKKAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACckl9rwyAUxd8H+w7B90RtyxiSpNCN7mWFwTo29iZ628qiEbVN+

+1nkjbL/jzt0Zxzf55zTT4/6io5gPOqNgWiGUEJGFFLZbYFelkv01uU

+MCN5FVtoEAn8GheXl/lwjJRO3hytQUXFPgkkoxnwhZoF4JlGHuxA819Fh0mipvaaR7i0W2x5eKDbwFPCLnBGgKXPHDcAlM7ENEZKcWAtHtXdQApMFS

gwQSPaUbxlzeA0/7PgU4ZObUKJxs7neOO2VL04uA+ejUYm6bJmmkXI+an

+G31+NxVTZVpdyUAlbkUTDjgoXblA987fkgWOx4Uz/FIabdYcR9WceEbBXJx+mn+bWhnHBxU

+2LlJMfjY7y1K9lfDTKJsVlf8qK8Tu/u10tUTgidpZSkdLamhNEZI+S9zfZtvq3Rf9DnhP8mXgBll/j7r1N

+AgAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEAaBAaatsHAACBPQAADwAAAHdvcmQvc3R5bGVzLnhtbMSbbXObOBDH39/MfQeG96kfksbXTN1OmrbXzPQhrZO51z

LIsSaAfICbpJ/+ViusYDCwG+jcqwSM9rfSrv6LE+3rtw9x5P2UaaZ0MvcnL8a+J5NAhyq5nfs31x

+P/vK9LBdJKCKdyLn/KDP/7Zs//3h9f5blj5HMPDCQZGdxMPfXeb45G42yYC1jkb3QG5nAhyudxiKHy/R2FIv0brs5CnS8Eblaqkjlj6PpeHzqF2ZSi

hW9WqlAvtfBNpZJjuNHqYzAok6ytdpkO2v3FGv3Og03qQ5klsGk48jai4VKnJnJSc1QrIJUZ3qVv4DJjKxHI2MKhk/G+Fsc

+V4cnF3eJjoVywgW735y4r+BlQt18F6uxDbKM3O
ZXqXFZXGFPz7qJM+8+zORBUpdw5KCgViBrU/nSaZ8+ESKLD/PlDj44do8dfCTIMtL1t6pUPkjQ8x

+gc2fIpr70+nuzoXxYO9eJJLb3T2ZHN0syp7MfXdrCXbnvkiPFufG2AinuftZmu5mb/Jwha5sRADBAI5Y5RKSAnLEcCJlcnA6g3yxFz

+2Zl3FNtcFBA0ArGwWLisrDrkCmbOwCQyfytVnHdzJcJHDB3MfWXDz5vIqVTqFJJ37r14ZJtxcyFh9UmEozX4p7t0kaxXKf9Yyuclk+HT/

+0dM/sJioLdJDu6fzjALoiz88BDIjUlbMJ0IE+GvZgAkDoSjxEGHturJG3ujQsWb/+6QExvDg5S1FGaHe+h/Kwhnve0NmpoZlSeAdlm

+Hvc3cdLfxMv+JjB5+63FrL8XoOt9I2Jzo5SV9KDmOrDJV16H41ctKWtG1LKoc0QtaTpH1HKkc0QtJTpH1DKgc0Qt4J0javHtHFELZ

+uIQKBwVbPoGFeDtLGvVR5JM75VgCY9pa4oNd6VSMVtKjZrzxTWqtttYrnYLnOaqyinzxfLRZ7q5LZzRaA6m637bE3+EG/WIlPwltSx9NOeS39t3nq8

v1MVdqJe2uSrzQlfTA6WsKtIBHKto1Cm3rV8sBFljP+qvYV9y

+h0rmdYP6vbde4t1lhyO2GnDYvevBLW/meV4Rq0bqbThql0GSfF8LQhL5uNf5Gh2sa7pSG8jZxaPWeEuYJAF9uX6MSEqL67OmdhAkCZgi0X/CmgfYL/

trjw7ZsYU/y3peiZ9gn+28L1TPuYH

+3xZSvNe/jS6pG214y9dy90pNPVNtrtgU55mLF3sEPQpsDexM4+SSRm7B28J5/eeRDANzdKnrJj8aSjDAo7HJaCm40+F3ZQKrI3YcyIHaAKa8pg9dNa

Bogtuj/kT2X+JsYtBqjS7l2zczsfN6wAlCDSO/T3rc6736GnDZpHpVwm8OeSTHo02nHDzqPSinyy9Y4R436FjwHqVwEZoH6lkAFqyI/mdx5XE+mQ
/sWRwWLLsqtimHZkZZ6xldmBeCVgoLpJeP9q2L3NuVCvmwQKO0D1ukmgsKNTqWWubhJYg9VNAquhajTHqKypnEmx62YZ5N4ECDMaRrwJoGHEmwAaRrw

JoP7i3Q0ZTrwJLLY2OE0tizcBhI9wvuo7UFm8CSC2Nli1K/5mtKt7aKX9y

+0A4k2gsANUF28ChR2dJvEmsPARTiZUWE7qCKxhxJsAGka8CaBhxJsAGka8CaBhxJsA6i/e3ZDhxJvAYmuD09SyeBNAbHlwoLJ4E0D4CEcbDoo37vrf

Lt4ECjtAdfEmUNjRqQiqe0klsNgBqrCceBNY

+AgnGQoWJjdnUsOIN2FGw4g3ATSMeBNAw4g3AdRfvLshw4k3gcXWBqepZfEmgNjy4EBl8SaA2NpwULxxM/528SZQ2AGqizeBwo5ORVCdzhFY7ABVWE6

8CSzMl97iTQDhI88FcWY0jHgTZjSMeBNAw4g3AdRfvLshw4k3gcXWBqepZfEmgNjy4EBl8SaA2NpwULxxj/x28SZQ2AGqizeBwo5ORVCdeBNY7ABVWE

7qCKxhxJsAwsTsLd4EED7yDBDuIk6YhhFvwoyGEW8CqL94d0OGE28Ci60NTlPL4k0AseXBgcriTQCxtcGcs4XzouTjqZOGJKCeM9idaiADpw1BogKLC

f6QK5lCk5XsPh3SE7ibIYPYkB7UKb7T+s6jHew+bkgQMkotI6XxSPcjntIpNSIcz1o6Ca6/XXifbANMbRym1P7JG

+geKrcLYXuSaRwCP/PHDbTsbHYny401aBAyfV1FCxC2yF1CQ1DR1mMGmz4feBCbqorb

+H/bggq/AxEH1lHBGlgBdES1oIoD7+4MEh53r4IbTsWjI08tGTs3i9PxT

+9Q9rm9M5qtfufmJHiLz3hSvHWNPHzERrXuIDRnoUtdHkLIlpFtMYNfLpMQZghNgvhfMxvM8EFYU/D5hYyiLwIb0nK9aX40kqvcfjoZYwWsmFrqPNdx

8/gUD4ijJ4cMQDqUnbGXZhLNeZJs4
6VMocOrZc2/alM5sBNtPyXtWdeGVKCudLNve9vFbZB3Ioq0TvAkfzVZi8/sMX/0aymgze6b6ZqrbSNoEbzb3S8ZvYCd0z97oE3WpAxCx+Ppy8kU

+l3Qo6bGRUytom3xxF0cblssWiThx17v59y/FmsdCxNL7Oos3wgyd2V3gGvinJwWe

+LXUxOnvQexgZbTtvzZ05lgm0H6YrNkVdaqC9wWOe8pBJXwHVQsnE1DMJmBbI4aLsP/sN673ZG9+Q8AAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhANStIeTrAQAA

qwUAABIAAAB3b3JkL2ZvbnRUYWJsZS54bWy0k1Fr2zAQx98H+w5G740lx8laU6e0WQN72cPoPoCiyLGYJRmdEi/ffifL8WAhtF6pDMb+n+7P3Y

+7+4ffukmO0oGypiRsRkkijbA7ZfYl+fmyubklCXhudryxRpbkJIE8rD5/uu

+KyhoPCeYbKLQoSe19W6QpiFpqDjPbSoPByjrNPf66faq5+3Vob4TVLfdqqxrlT2lG6ZIMNu4tLraqlJBfrThoaXyfnzrZoKM1UKsWzm7dW9w663ats

0ICYM+6iX6aKzPasPzCSCvhLNjKz7CZNFaUBitMZ7T/0g1JtCi

+7Y11fNsgu47lZDWAS7rCcI3imjdq61QfaLmxIBnGjrwpCc3ohi7wHZ6czsObpMFB1NyB9ONFGuWKa9Wczip0CiAGWuVFfdaP3KlQUAyB2mPgAFtakm

eKJ9tsSFRYSXIUHtejkmFR8bDhznxUcHKwsN6nv8Lueh9U0GfI6utM4+hckHhRWkLyXXbJD6u5uUIko0sksUAegcx8EhHX+/YEJxDJHsf

+sZM1tvLlNj/3/5fI3etEos8EIrzGiq+AeEIQYSgCivzjR4PhZDz/C2JJF09D2yOI7DUQjLKpINZc445cIxFGIXIIozFtSf5vJC6XhOYjm5EE7VcCV

+s9SzJsC6z+AAAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEA5NMa63UBAADHAgAAEAAIAWRvY1
Byb3BzL2FwcC54bWwgogQBKKAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACcUstOwzAQvCPxD1Hu1GmFEFRbI9QKceBRqWk5W/YmsXBsyzaI/j2bpk2DuOHTzqw9nh0b7r9bk31hiNrZRT6dFHmGVj

qlbb3It+Xj1W2exSSsEsZZXOR7jPk9v7yAdXAeQ9IYM5KwcZE3Kfk5Y1E22Io4obalTuVCKxLBUDNXVVriysnPFm1is6K4Yfid0CpUV34QzHvF

+Vf6r6hysvMXd+Xek2EOJbbeiIT8tbNjJsqlFtjAQumSMKVukRdEDwDWosbIp8D6At5dUJFfA

+sLWDYiCJkoPz67ATaC8OC90VIkCpa/aBlcdFXK3g4RZN1xYOMtQLFsUH4GnfadiTGEZ217G31BtoKog/DN0duAYCOFwSXNzithIgI7E7B0rRd2z8nn

qSK9j7j1pVt14RyP/CZHM77r1Gy8kORldjeedtSADUWCiuyf5M4EPNFzBNPdSUnZGtVpz99Gl9+u/5d8ej0paB0CO3H0JMOH4T8AAAD//wMAUEsBAi0

AFAAGAAgAAAAhAAkkh4KBAQAAjgUAABMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFtDb250ZW50X1R5cGVzXS54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAHpEat/MAAABOAg

AACwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC6AwAAX3JlbHMvLnJ
lbHNQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAfDuXOSIBAAC5AwAAHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADeBgAAd29yZC9fcmVscy9kb2N1bWVudC54bWwucmVsc1BLAQItABQABg

AIAAAAIQBRbm8SgQIAAEwHAAARAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEIJAAB3b3JkL2RvY3VtZW50LnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQAw3UMpqAYAAKQbAAAVAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAPILAAB3b3JkL3RoZW1lL3RoZW1lMS54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEA0c5eAHwDAACwCAAAEQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADNEgAAd29yZC9z

ZXR0aW5ncy54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAF6AWTgIBAACsAQAAFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB4FgAAd29yZC93ZWJTZXR0aW5ncy54bWxQSwECLQAUAAY

ACAAAACEAhu5W3l8IAAByQAAAGgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACsFwAAd29yZC9zdHlsZXNXaXRoRWZmZWN0cy54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAGq47i0wBAA

CHAgAAEQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABDIAAAZG9jUHJvcHMvY29yZS54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAaBAaatsHAACBPQAADwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADGIgAAd

29yZC9zdHlsZXMueG1sUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhANStIeTrAQAAqwUAABIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAzioAAHdvcmQvZm9udFRhYmxlLnhtbFBLAQItABQA

BgAIAAAAIQDk0xrrdQEAAMcCAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOksAABkb2NQcm9wcy9hcHAueG1sUEsFBgAAAAAMAAwACQMAAJQvAAAAAA==";

and my 1st word file contains data

as Hi <>

How are you?

and output file is

Hi <>

How are you?

I need to read the contains of file through stream and store it using stram as given in code

can any body helps..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do some kind of mail merging where you have your template document with placeholders and some data to fill into those placeholders to get the output document which keeps the formatting of the template.

I am solving these kind of tasks by using a toolkit which supports OpenXML and uses previously designed Word template (formatting and placeholders). Data is prepared in .NET application (collections of data model classes). Template file can be read as filestream (as in your scenario) or by referrencing a file path. At the end you get a new Word docx document which keeps the formatting of the template and contains the data. Take a look at [this example.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/759408/Creating-Word-documents-in-Net-using-Docentric-Too)